# Return a values into a list

Tags: python, list

I want to write a function that should return the values in a range into a `list`, but it rather prints them out. This is the code

```
def fun(n):
    for i in range(n +1):
        k = i**1
        print k
```

Comment: The values are printing because you've got `print k` in your function.

Comment: Learn about lists at pages like this: http://www.learnpython.org/en/Lists

Comment: It's printing instead of returning because you told it to print instead of return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a `list` at first and then [`append`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) to it

```
def fun(n):
    l = []
    for i in range(n +1):
        k = i**1
        l.append(k)
    return l
```

You could be better off using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
def fun(n):
    return [i**1 for i in range(n+1)]
```

As you can see this is better and simple!

Answer (score 0):

He could also have an even simpler solution:

```
f = lambda n: [i**1 for i in range(n+1)]
print(f(10))
```